Directions for a 'Popcorn Avalanche' scene in Unreal
I have an interior scene that I'd like to flood with popcorn. This scene is roughly 20mx30m.
I've tried variations of two approaches so far:

Bruteforce niagara with particles.
High viscosity liquid simulation
in blender

But I can't get the material right for the second one, can I have more perspectives on this problem?

It might help to show the results you've gotten so far, versus your visual target for what it should look like. In what way is the material not right in the second strategy? What specific aspects should answers focus on improving? Can you edit your question to include this detail?

Honestly, I'm looking for general high level guidance. I'm afraid showing my current results won't really help with that. I love how friendly this website is towards strictly non-technical (but still technical) questions, regarding the downvote.

We're just looking for more clarity on what help you need. There's a good chance that no one reading your question has ever made a popcorn avalanche effect before, so even if you're unhappy with your results so far, you're still the subject matter expert in the room by virtue of having tried something — you know the specifics of what you tried and how those attempts fell short. If you can show/explain what went wrong ("I can't get the material right" — what's not "right" about it, or what qualities are you looking for to call something "right"?) we can better help you improve the effect.

I'm one of the close votes. Like DMGregory said we need to know what you have tried and why that failed. For example why can't you just create individual popcorn entities and let them enter the room using a normal physics simulation? Too many entities (did you actually check the performance or just guessing?)? Looks weird? Especially in regards to your last sentence "But I can't get the material right for the second one", I'm not sure how we are supposed to help if we don't know what it looks like and what is "not right" about it :P
